# How can I see frames per second (fps) of a game?

Tags: games

I'm playing [Magic: Arena](https://store.epicgames.com/en-US/p/mtg-arena) on my M1 MacBook Pro. It's a game that's available exclusively through the Epic Games Store. There is no way to show the frames per second inside the game. There used to be, but the developers disabled the feature at some point.

The reason I would like to see the frame rate is to help me choose the ideal graphics quality level for my machine.

I tried the [Count It](https://www.macgamerhq.com/count-it-mac-frame-rate/) app, but it just stays at zero when trying to measure it. Also, it's authors say it's unstable and it hasn't apparently been updated in the last four years.

Comment: You could potentially install Apple developer's Quartz Debug tool to see general FPS of your macOS desktop? It's a bit complicated to explain all the steps here, but I've found some instructions here: https://osxdaily.com/2015/04/02/monitor-frames-per-second-fps-live-mac-os-x/ You don't need to have an Apple developer account to download this tool and you don't need to download the entire XCode app either. Just log-in with your Apple ID and follow the instructions on the website above. Let me know if you need any help :)

Comment: P.S. The website's instructions were last updated in 2015, but the instructions are still the same except instead of downloading "Graphic Tools for XCode" from Apple's developer website, you just need to download "Additional Tools for XCode", as they've just packaged all the graphics, hardware, audio tools in one download file.